# How to make Live Server USB with updated package

Tags: server, system-installation

How do I make a new version of the `ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso` with an updated version of the installer (in particular curtin).

I need to do this because I am experiencing a bug that was fixed in curtin version18.1-17-gae48e86f-0ubuntu1 but no new ISO's have been released yet.

**Bug Report:** https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1767584

**Fixed In:** https://git.launchpad.net/curtin/commit/?id=c8209ef76ff332b1dd004329437a46338105b9ab

**Edit:** I would use the alternate installer except it suffers from another bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/os-prober/+bug/1663645) that also effects me.

**Edit:** Ended up using the alternative installer and removed all drives, except the OS drive to avoid the bug above.

Comment: Link to the bug report + fix please?

Comment: @sudodus [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1046549/#comment1707295_1046549) looks like the beginnings of an answer (at least to me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the Bionic daily iso files at the QA iso testing tracker. See [this link with a live-server 'Subiquity' iso file from yesterday](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/384/builds).

At that link there is also the old style server iso file with the classic Debian installer (from today) according to what I see right now. This iso file might also work for you.

If the Subiquity iso file is not updated with the bug-fixed installer today, maybe it will be there tomorrow.

Edit:

It seems that the links from the QA iso testing tracker to the [iso] files are broken. This link works for me,

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/bionic/daily-live/pending/

to get the Subiquity server iso file.

The following link works to get the old style server iso file,

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/bionic/daily/pending/

---

The daily iso files of the future version, now Cosmic, should not be recommended for a server (except for testing), but here we are talking about Bionic daily iso files, which belong to the released version 18.04 LTS (and will developed into the point releases 18.04.1 - 18.04.5 in due time). This development is slower and less prone to show-stopping bugs, so I think you can consider using them, at least until there is a released version, that works for you.

Edit:
An alternative approach.

If that approach doesn't work for you you can always [manually customize the live iso](https://askubuntu.com/a/49679/225694) to suit your needs. The package you desire is available in the repositories [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/curtin)

Comment: The link to the ISO is dead.  The only daily builds are for Cosmic.

Comment: @MichaelR.Shannon, I found working links and added them to the answer.

Comment: I made a minor edit in an attempt to improve your answer. If this doesn't meet with your approval, feel free to roll it back. Cheers!

Comment: The daily image is broken, but I accepted the answer since it does answer the question.